# formatting constexpr if in c++-mode

Tags: indentation, c++, cc-mode

I recently started using C++17, which brings constexpr if. This however screws up `c++-mode`s default indentation.

```
// emacs 25.3.2 with --no-init
if constexpr (n == 1) {
    // Why?
  } else if constexpr (n == 2) {
    // This is a mess...
  } else {
  // and it keeps getting weird
}
```

Does anyone either

1. Know of a simpler alternative to cc-mode?
2. Know how i can fix this particular issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE:** That pretest version that I put down there in the original question (`emacs-26.0.90.tar.gz`) had a bug that cause certain infinity loops while parsing the buffer, specifically when using the `<` token in certaing contexts, like writting `<` as the first character of an empty buffer in Java or C++ or after the keyword `template`. The bug has been fixed in the `emacs-26` branch, so that is what you have to download instead.

---

It took a lot to me to find the answer and learning how to property customize the behaviour in the elisp language but, a way of fixing that is by telling to the `cc-mode` that `constexpr` is a "noise name", which means that it will be treated as a whitespace and thus ignored by the parser.

The thing is that in the last stable release of emacs (25.3), the feature of adding noise words is not added, even when it is in the repo since February 2016, so you have to download the a non-release version.

```
cd tmp_folder_of_your_choice

sudo apt-get install build-essential # if you don't have it yet
sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24 # get all dependancies to build emacs

# Not this: wget https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/archive/emacs-26.0.90.tar.gz

wget -O emacs-26.zip https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/archive/e8636ac8cc96e1e7e948f04091792da09dafcc76.zip

# or just the last version of the branch, but the exact version I have is the one above
# wget https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/archive/emacs-26.zip

unzip emacs-26.zip
cd emacs-emacs-26

./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
emacs ~/.emacs
```

And then, for example at the end of the `.emacs` file, add:

```
; Load the mode before-hand to make the symbols visible
(require 'cc-mode)
(custom-set-variables '(c-noise-macro-names '("constexpr")))
```

Comment: while this is great, and im trying it out now, it still kinda feels like a hack - is there a better way to add it in just that one syntactic position?

Comment: I don't know, but this solution works perfectly for me.

Comment: yeah, it does work for me, with [this awesome project](https://github.com/Wilfred/remacs) as well as the latest emacs git

Comment: @topisani Please, could you see that question if the same happens to you after installing the last emacs version? https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/36423/14016